# How to make item more tight (less white space) in PopupMenu when FieldSize is not enough

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to format a PopupMenu, and noticed when I make the FieldSize->7, then one of the items in the menu will wrap around to a newline, even though it seems to me that there is was enoughwhite space it could have used to the right.

When I increased FieldSize->8 then the fieldSize is now enough, and none of the menu items will wrap around.

But it seems to me there is allot of white space wasted now. I tried many options for the PopupMenu, such as ContentPadding, and such to make the items more tight, but it insists on wrapping that one item when I set the fieldSize back to 7.

May be it is a font style issue?  I was wondering if someone might have a trick around this.

Here is the code, and showing the problem

```
Manipulate[
opt,

Control[{ {opt,0,Style["display",11]},
  {0->Text@Style["bob only",Small],
  4->Text@Style["L + bob",Small],
  1->Text@Style["L only",Small],
  2->Text@Style["L resolved",Small],
  3->Text@Style["L + resolved",Small],
  5->Text@Style["L resolved + bob",Small],
  6->Text@Style["show all above",Small]        
},
ControlType->PopupMenu,FieldSize->7,
ImageMargins->0,
FrameMargins->0,ContentPadding->True,ImageSize->Small}]

]
```

Here is a screen shot when I open the menu

[image]

So, now I change FieldSize->8 and now it looks like this:

[image]

But notice above, I think there is too much white space on the right, and FieldSize->7 should have been wide enough for that item to not have wrapped around?.

I tried FontFamily->"Times" and "Courier", and same effect:

```
Manipulate[opt,
Control[{ {opt,0,Style["display",11]},
{0->Text@Style["bob only",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
4->Text@Style["L + bob",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
1->Text@Style["L only",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
2->Text@Style["L resolved",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
3->Text@Style["L + resolved",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
5->Text@Style["L resolved + bob",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"],
6->Text@Style["show all above",Small,FontFamily->"Courier"]
},ControlType->PopupMenu,FieldSize->7,
ImageMargins->0,FrameMargins->0,ContentPadding->True,ImageSize->Small}]
]
```

Actually now with Courier, I had to go to FieldSize->9 for that one field to not wrap around now. So it got worst with Courier.

Is it possible to make the field more tight than it is?

EDIT 1:
Reply to MrWizard:
[image]
[image]

EDIT 2:

Using FieldSize->Automatic, cause the overall Menu size to change size depending on the item selected.

```
Manipulate[opt,Control[{{opt,0,Style["display",11]},
{0->Style["bob only",Small],
1->Style["L + bob",Small],
2->Style["L only",Small],
3->Style["L resolved",Small],
4->Style["L + resolved",Small],
5->Style["L resolved + bob",Small],
6->Style["show allabove",Small]},
ControlType->PopupMenu,FieldSize->Automatic,
ImageMargins->0,FrameMargins->0,ImageSize->Small}]]
```

**Update dec 21 1 AM**

This diagram belows shows how to use Leonid macro method to make it easier
to build UI and reduce code duplication for UI object customization by use
of macros. I currently use this method heavily and have a complex UI of over
4,000 lines just for the UI itself, and I could not have done this the old way, 
because I would simply lose control of things.

Macros make it easier to manage the code layout, and more important, now I
can change the UI itself very easily by editing small code instead of
the larger code which the macro represent. Without a GUI builder, macros
are the next best thing :)

[image]

Here is the code for the above

```
Manipulate[

 Row[{opt1, opt2}],

 Evaluate@With[{
    popUpMenu1Options = MenuStyle -> {Red},
    popUpMenu2Options = MenuStyle -> {Black},
    popUpMenuCommonOptions = {BaseStyle -> 20, ImageMargins -> 0, 
      FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> All}
    },

   With[{

     menu1 = PopupMenu[Dynamic[opt1],
       {"A", "B"
        }, Sequence[popUpMenu1Options, popUpMenuCommonOptions]
       ],
     menu2 = PopupMenu[Dynamic[opt2],
       {"C", "D"
        }, Sequence[popUpMenu2Options, popUpMenuCommonOptions]
       ]
     },

    Row[{menu1, menu2}]

    ]
   ],

 {{opt1, "A"}, None},
 {{opt2, "D"}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {opt1, opt2}
 ]
```

Comment: If you use `FieldSize->Automatic` then everything resizes automatically. Is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: This solution does not work since the overall size of the popup menu will change depending on the item selected, as was my answer earlier to MrWizad. When the popupMenu is part of larger UI, then the overall UI will shift a little or resize, which is annoying. This is why the fieldsize should be selected to fit the largest item. Please see EDIT 2.

Comment: Just checking! That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight modification based on Simon's answer works better:

```
Manipulate[opt, 
 Control[{{opt, 0, Style["display", 11]}, 
   {0 -> Style["bob only", Small],
    1 -> Style["L only", Small],  
    4 -> Style["L + bob", Small],
    2 -> Style["L resolved", Small], 
    3 -> Style["L + resolved", Small], 
    5 -> Style["L resolved + bob", Small], 
    6 -> Style["show all above", Small]}, 
 ControlType -> PopupMenu, 
 ImageMargins -> 0, 
 FrameMargins -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> All}]]
```

[image]

Comment: how do you like that. So, the trick is to use ImageSize->All ? That is the only difference that I see from what you have there and from what I had. I used ImageSize->Small. This is nice. Never occurred to me to consider looking at the ImageSize option as I always use Small for setting the Manipulate controls. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove all of the `Text@` stuff because it causes lines to appear blank on my system.

There appear to be two issues here.

- You can use a fractional `FieldSize`
- You must account for the width of the drop-down arrow

You can see that I can get a reasonably tight fit on the longest line with this:

```
Manipulate[opt, 
 Control[{{opt, 0, 
    Style["display", 11]}, {0 -> Style["bob only", Small], 
    4 -> Style["L + bob", Small], 1 -> Style["L only", Small], 
    2 -> Style["L resolved", Small], 
    3 -> Style["L + resolved", Small], 
    5 -> Style["L resolved + bob", Small], 
    6 -> Style["show all above", Small]}, ControlType -> PopupMenu, 
   FieldSize -> 6.4, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> Small}]]
```

[image]

Generally I think *Mathematica* does well not to squish the text into the arrow.  I don't know of a way to achieve that effect, if that is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code on my system (windows 7, Mathematica 8.0.1), but this field still wraps around?. Please see EDIT 1.

Comment: @Nasser my font settings are probably different, my OS is different, and my window style is different.  It is no surprise that it wraps at a different `FieldSize` for me than it does for you.  6.4 was the smallest one tenth value that did not wrap in my particular case.

Comment: @MrWizard, Yes, I understand. I waslooking for a setting or font style where it will work the same way regardless of the platform. thanks.

Comment: @Nasser: The appearance of many items in Mathematica are system dependent, which is good, since otherwise Mathematica would look out of place in most systems. This includes fonts, menu objects, buttons, etc... (Comments hadn't refreshed... sorry for repeating what Mr.W said!)

Comment: @Nasser, you did not specify that in your question.  You should.  I do not think what you want is possible, because as I just unintentionally demonstrated, there are things outside your control that will change when the wrap occurs.  I believe you are better off omitting `FieldSize` and letting Mathematica fit it accordingly.

Comment: @MrWizard, if I do not use FieldSize, then the Manipulate interface will shift or change size as one selects different items which can be of different width. This is not good. I wanted the UI to be fixed in size, hence looked for largest field size to do the job. But this largest fieldsize, might not be enough it seems on different platform. I'd like to make the UI look the same on each platform if possible. I think Mathematica runs on Mac and Linux only in addition to windows. Any way, thanks for trying it on your OS.

Comment: @Nasser, I am sorry I don't have a more helpful answer for you, but I will be glad to try any GUI you come up with on my mma7/WinXP set and post pictures.

Comment: @MrWizard, thanks for the offer. I try a CDF on Linux and windows 8. But do not have a mac. There are small differences in the UI as can be expected between windows and linux. For example, a Checkbox on window looks different than a Checkbox on linux. etc.. I just tried the fieldSize->8 on a demo I am writing now on linux and it did work the same as on windows. Did not wrape. UI size did not change. good. if you want to try it on your OS, please see this table, there is a link there to the CDF. First one on table, #19 is the one.
http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/KERNEL/KERNEL.htm

Comment: @Nasser since it sounds like belisarius solved your problem, do you still want me to try this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that a dumb fix would be to just pad all of the strings to the same (maximum) length, then use `FieldSize->Automatic`.

```
StringPad[str_String,n_Integer] := StringJoin[PadRight[Characters[str], n, " "]]

menuItems = {0->"bob only", 1->"L only",
             2->"L resolved", 3->"L + resolved",
             4->"L + bob", 5->"L resolved + bob",
             6->"show all above"};

maxStr = Max@StringLength@menuItems[[All,2]]

(* Out[3]= 16*)

f[str_String] := StringPad[str, maxStr]

Manipulate[opt,Control[{{opt,0,Style["display",11]},
           MapAt[f,#,2]&/@menuItems,
           ControlType->PopupMenu, FieldSize->maxStr,
           ContentPadding->False, ImageMargins->0,
           FrameMargins->0, ImageSize->Small}]]
```

This could be automated in your own custom `PopupMenu`.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. I tried actually padding with spaces, and I tried also your code above, tried with different values for padding which you have above. But still the overall menu size does change depending on which item selected. If you keep your eyes on the menu frame, you'll notice it changes/resizes as different item is selected. I also tried using Spacer[], but not working. I find using spaces to force formatting does not work well. For now, I'll stick with fieldSize-> large enough, and live with the extra white space. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser: If you set the `FieldSize` to the padded string size it works. (FieldSize is measured in ems, so the lengths should basically match up). I've edited my answer - it works on my machine.

Comment: I tried your edited answer. Yes, now the menu do not change size. But I found that if I use "maxstr-5" in you code above, it also works. The field was actually more tight now. (I kept subtracting one from maxstr until it no longer worked. At maxstr-6 field did wrap around. So, I guess one still needs to do some trial and error to find the 'optimal'  FieldSize for the popupMenu. Thanks

Comment: @Nasser: Well, the real trick is to measure the longest string in units of [ems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)). Since [Mma measures FieldSize in ems](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FieldSize.html). That said, I'm not sure which character has width equal to 1em in the Mma font. Try `InputField[StringJoin@Table["M", {#}], String, 
 FieldSize -> #]&[5]` with different choices of "M" and 5. `"\[ThickSpace]\[ThinSpace]M"` comes close...

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this while looking for an answer to something else. Where possible i like to separate the styling from the functionality, so for examples like those above my preference would be to only list one set of style options rather than style each label e.g.

```
Manipulate[opt,
 Style[
  Control[{{opt, 0, "display"}, {0 -> "bob only", 1 -> "L only", 
     4 -> "L + bob", 2 -> "L resolved", 3 -> "L + resolved", 
     5 -> "L resolved + bob", 6 -> "show all above"}, 
    ControlType -> PopupMenu}], 
  DefaultOptions -> {PopupMenu -> {BaseStyle -> 10, ImageMargins -> 0,
       FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> All, MenuStyle -> {Red, 11}}}]]
```

Comment: thanks for that. But for a complex UI what if one wants to have different style for one Popup menu vs. the other? Would not setting defaultOptions affect all? Same for Plot, etc..? For having a common subset, your solution is good. But I now use Leonid macro method for doing this sort of thing. I set up macros for what I need, and just use the macro name itself to refer to what I want. I think it is more customizable. I'll show an example above of what I mean, just give me little time. The macro method is powerful once one gets used to it and safe since a macro is just code replacement.

Comment: by definition if you want to style elements differently you need to set those styles specifically for each element. However if e.g. you had say one style in a block different to the rest you could do something like this and style the one exception specifically. At the end of the day to each his own ...just thought I'd put it out there because I tend to use it all the time in code blocks.